# Formatting the font of ticklabels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a font dictionary with which I would like to format the ticklabels in a matplotlib plot.

The [`Axes.set_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) function comes with a warning that the method should only be used after fixing the tick positions using `Axes.set_xticks`. To set the ticks, I need to give them positions. I want to use the default positions and numerical formatting provided by matplotlib, and only specify the way in which the *text* is to be formatted.

How can I do this?

My initial attempt

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), fontdict=mydict)
```

works, vis a vis the font formatting, but the ticklabels don't change on zooming, and the numerical formatting changed (eg originally 10, afterwards 10.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use pyplot [`xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) with no ticks or labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydict = {'fontweight': 'bold'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(**mydict)
```

[image]

If you want to use the OOP interface, you can achieve the same by

```
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.update(mydict)
```

Comment: I'm using the OOP interface, as I'm passing figures and axes around to different functions to do things.. I'll see how this works..

Comment: @masher please see the updated answer for this case

Comment: Ta a lot! Still learning where everything is in the docs. That loop is what I'm after.